# How to sum from a related table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a main table, and a sub table. The Main table is the master list of parts, the sub table are the collective parts needed to build it. Each child part is linked to it's parent part through a ParentID.

The part or 'child' has a ChildID which points to it's own entry inside of the main parts list. We use this link to get it's price, as inside the subtable, only the ID is stored.

If I wanted to sum together the total cost of all of those child parts which make up each Parent part. How would I structure that query?

Total cost should be a calculated field which selects all the parts in the subtable that have a ParentID == to it's ID and sums their price * Qty.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//This Query Doesnt work. Just returns 0.
SELECT SUM(PricePer * Qty)
    FROM sub inner join main on sub.ChildPID = main.ID where sub.ParentPID = main.ID

//This query will work, where the main.ID is entered manually. but I cant do this
SELECT SUM(PricePer * Qty)
    FROM sub inner join main on sub.ChildPID = main.ID where sub.ParentPID = 1
```

---

EXAMPLE:

Main Table

```
ID | Name | TotalCost | PricePer 

1    Part1  10.00       14.00**   SELECTED

2    Part2  0.00        6.00

3    Part3  0.00        2.00
```

Sub Table

```
ParentID | ChildID | Name | Qty

1          2         Part2  1

1          3         Part3  2
```

Comment: Hello, here some links to help you to structure your question : 
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info 

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expectedc result .. and add  the rest of the query too  .. (seems you are using columns related to the outer part of the query  ... ParentID)

Comment: sub left join main seems a bit backward.

Comment: Updated with an example. Not sure what's backwards. but I know that something here doesn't make sense the way I've written it.

Comment: It is a typical tree. Do you have any limit for the depth of the tree? e.g. part, subpart, subsubpart, ...? Or can you set a technical limit for that, e.g maximum 5?

Comment: no limit. A part can have a sub part, which has sub parts itself, and so on.

Comment: In this case you cannot resolve it with one statement in MySQL. If you could say that e.g. the depth is maximum 10, then with 9 joins you could grab them. Otherwise you either need to maintain an indirect descendancy table (not only holding the direct dependency, but up to the root, everything), or you need a loop to determine the dependencies in a temporary table, then sum up everything. It also matters how complex your structure may be (the same subpart can be used for different main parts, etc)

Comment: What if you only ever needed to look one level deep. Because each part has a PricePer stored in the main table? PricePer is different from TotalCost in that it's manually entered and stored instead of calculated.

Comment: If you are selecting a part, you want to know the total price for that part, right? including subparts, subsubparts, ...
The only thing that can help you if you can define an ordering, where the subparts can be calculated first, then its parents, then its parents... etc. 
For example, if a parent always has a smaller ID than its child, if we order by ID DESC, we can process the tree leaves first, then the branches, etc...

Comment: what if we only want to process one level deep? If you look in my example, the prices are all defined. I'd just like a column used to roughly verify that the subparts total up to roughly the entered value.

Comment: It does not help. It's easy to construct such a query, but the descendants wont work. I can sketch it as an answer, and tomorrow refine it

Comment: even if the descendants (sub table entries) don't need any calculated / rolled up cost to be shown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became more convoluted than I think it needed to be. Maybe that's my fault for not making it more clear. Here's the solution I found that worked.

```
Select *, ifnull((SELECT SUM(main.PricePer * Qty)
    FROM sub inner join main on sub.ChildID = main.ID where sub.ParentID = main1.PID), 0) from main as main1
```

Comment: Hi! in this solution you do not consider subsubparts (level 2, level 3, etc),

Answer (score 1):

you should not  use a where clause in a left join  cause otherwise this work as a inner join
and if you want join the result with an upper query  .. you sould sum and group by the key you want relate to thge upper query

the you could directly  .. perform an update based  on the joined  result eg:

```
update main  
inner join  (
  SELECT  main.ID, SUM(main.PricePer) total_x_id
  FROM sub 
  INNER  join main on sub.ChildID = main.ID
  group by main.ID 
) t on t.id = main.id 
set total = t.total_x_id
```

if you just need the select  then

```
 SELECT  main.ID, SUM(main.PricePer) total_x_id
 FROM sub 
 INNER  join main on sub.ChildID = main.ID
 group by main.ID
```

you could get the result in the upper query using a join as

```
select  maint.id, ifnull(t.total_x_id ,0)
from main 
left  join (
  SELECT  ChildID.ID as ID, SUM(main.PricePer) total_x_id
  FROM sub 
  group by ChildID.ID 
) t  on t.ID = main.id
```

Comment: This is close to working, but it doesn't quite work. And the query needs to be a select, not an update. The value represented in the table isn't stored. It's calculated.

Comment: This has been very helpful! Final portion of this, how would I structure this to return as a column alongside out main table? This returns the column. but how would I structure this to align beside a SELECT * on the main

Comment: Ok but how you want join this resutt to the  outer/upper query ?? .. the result proposed  in my answer  give the possibile of join the result with other query using  the id ... .. if you just want the total the you should filter the result by the id ..using a where clause based on you upper  query ..

Comment: I'd want to join the results with the upper query based on Where main.id = sub.parentId

Comment: this is so so so close to working. 

but it's totaling the price for the main part, and not all the individual subparts. So for example, in my example above, part 3 would have a totalCost of 4, but part 1 would have a totalCost of 0. In other words. It's selecting every sub line that has a ChildId == the main.Id and totalling that selection

Comment: still the same. this is calculating the totalCost for all of the times the main part has appeared in other parts subtables. so a $50 part, that's appeared in three other parts subtables, has a totalCost of $150 instead of 47.82 or whatever the subparts would have added up to.

Comment: then you don't need the join in subquery  .. but just a sum group by answer  updated

Comment: we need the join subquery to get the priceper of the sub parts. The subtable only stores the ID. We need to go to the main table to get the priceper of the Children

Comment: I figured it out with your help. I appreciate the time you lent to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the select for one level:

```
SELECT m.priceper + SUM(s1.qty * m2.priceper) AS priceper
FROM main m
LEFT JOIN sub s1 ON (m.id = s1.parentid)
LEFT JOIN main m2 ON (m2.id = s1.childid)
-- WHERE m.id = 1
GROUP BY m.id;
```

For 2 levels, it is going to be something like this (I could not try it, maybe needs some fix):

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s1.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
FROM main m1
LEFT JOIN sub s1 ON (m1.id = s1.parentid)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m2.id, m2.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s2.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
    FROM main m2
    LEFT JOIN sub s2 ON (m2.id = s2.parentid)
    LEFT JOIN main g2 ON (g2.id = s2.childid)
    GROUP BY m2.id)
g2 ON (g2.id = s1.childid)
-- WHERE m1.id = 1
GROUP BY m1.id;
```

To drill down, you need to replace the main table with a subquery for g3, etc...

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s1.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
FROM main m1
LEFT JOIN sub s1 ON (m1.id = s1.parentid)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m2.id, m2.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s2.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
    FROM main m2
    LEFT JOIN sub s2 ON (m2.id = s2.parentid)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m3.id, m3.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s3.qty * g3.priceper),0) AS priceper
        FROM main m3
        LEFT JOIN sub s3 ON (m3.id = s3.parentid)
        LEFT JOIN main g3 ON (g3.id = s3.childid)
        GROUP BY m3.id) g2 
        ON (g2.id = s2.childid)
    GROUP BY m2.id) g2 
    ON (g2.id = s1.childid)
-- WHERE m1.id = 1
GROUP BY m1.id;
```

For 4 levels, it looks like this:

```
SELECT m1.id, m1.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s1.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
FROM main m1
LEFT JOIN sub s1 ON (m1.id = s1.parentid)
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT m2.id, m2.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s2.qty * g2.priceper),0) AS priceper
    FROM main m2
    LEFT JOIN sub s2 ON (m2.id = s2.parentid)
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT m3.id, m3.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s3.qty * g3.priceper),0) AS priceper
        FROM main m3
        LEFT JOIN sub s3 ON (m3.id = s3.parentid)
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT m4.id, m4.priceper + IFNULL(SUM(s4.qty * g4.priceper),0) AS priceper
            FROM main m4
            LEFT JOIN sub s4 ON (m4.id = s4.parentid)
            LEFT JOIN main g4 ON (g4.id = s4.childid)
            GROUP BY m4.id) g3
        ON (g3.id = s3.childid)
        GROUP BY m3.id) g2 
        ON (g2.id = s2.childid)
    GROUP BY m2.id) g2 
    ON (g2.id = s1.childid)
-- WHERE m1.id = 1
GROUP BY m1.id;
```

Comment: where does m1 come from?

Comment: Updated, check now

Comment: Alright this query gets stuck at ' Left join sub s2 on (m.id = s2.parentid)'   -  It doesn't recognize m.id , i'm not sure why

Comment: sorry I was wrong. I edited my comment, but maybe you didn't see. It's the line with m.id that's the issue which trickled down to g2 being an issue.

Comment: returns null :( Also, where m.id = 1 would have to become something like where m.id = s1.parentid so we got the whole table not just the result for 1.

This is much more convoluted than i'd originally thought it would be

Comment: I will check it tomorrow.

Comment: appreciate all the help. Thanks. Looking forward to seeing the work around tomorrow.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my answer. with more deeper queries.